# Fixed memory layout synchronized variables with references

Tags: c++, embedded, language-lawyer

Is it possible to create a class/struct which has a defined memory layout but has two variables which need to be sync without resorting to manually synchronising it with a function?

An example:

```
struct hardwareLayout{
    uint8_t regA;
    uint8_t regB;
    uint8_t regC;
}
```

`regA` and `regC` need to contain the exact same value at the same time (in spite of the writing of the data to the register being sequential). And are physically located at separate addresses in memory

In effect something like this is wat would be what I want:

```
struct abstractInterfaceToHardwareLayout{
    uint8_t regA;
    uint8_t regB;
    uint8_t& regC = regA;
}
```

And it would be used akin to:

```
abstractInterfaceToHardwareLayout& interface = static_cast<abstractInterfaceToHardwareLayout&>(pointerToBaseOfHardware);
interface.regA = 0x01;
//and as such interface.regC is also the value 0x01
```

The problem is that this can't be done because `regC` will be created by the compiler as a pointer to the `uint8_t regA` not an `uint8_t` value. And as such the memory layout of the interface will be:

```
uint8_t regA;
uint8_t regB;
pointer_to_uint8_t_with_value_semantics regC;
```

With possibly a different type width and discordant value inside `regC` as it is a pointer not a value.

The separate memory locations could be an requirement from an embedded device with memory-mapped-io which requires a certain memory layout for registers.

Comment: Create a class with setter functions that enforce the class invariant?  (and some getter functions).

Comment: I don't see the problem with `uint8_t& regC = regA;`. regC is not a pointer there, but a reference. `uint8_t* regC` would be a pointer.

Comment: So to be clear, `regC` has a unique address, but is always the same value as `regA`? If they have the same address, then a `union` might serve, but if it's two addresses, then `union`s won't work.

Comment: @MartinBonner That's indeed a (maybe even **the**) solution but I'm wondering if there is another way of doing that (and enforcing it) without resorting to manual management.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm supposing two different addresses some amount of bytes apart.

Comment: @FalcoGer: While it's not a C++ pointer, in practice, references in structs/classes are implemented as pointers (they're just automatically dereferenced any time you use them after initialization). So the memory layout wouldn't match.

Comment: @TarickWelling: Yeah, if the addresses must be separate, and the layout must be one byte for each, but the value must stay in sync, Martin Bonner's suggestion is really the only way to go. If the struct is actually being mapped over a DMA device that enforces this invariant for you, you could just declare both variables `volatile` to ensure they're always read from memory, not cached (so after writing to `regA`, reading from `regC` would see the updated value from the device), but if the struct doesn't always overlap the DMA addresses of the device, you're stuck with getters and setters.

Comment: make the struct a class and use setters and getters. otherwise I don't see why you'd need a fixed memory layout and reffer to the same variable with two names, and using twice the memory in the first place.
Alternatively use a class to manage the structure in code (with only one variable per value that's copied) and then build and return the structure when you need it with however many copies you want of the same value.

Comment: Certainly not _literally_  _"at the same time"_ - you'll have to define what you mean by that, if you don't mean it _literally_.  Create a member function that sets them both (in a critical section if there are multiple threads or the registers are accessed in interrupts), and make the register members themselves private to prevent access by any other means.

Comment: The sane solution is to update the whole struct with a single 32 bit write at once. This assuming that your system can do 32 bit writes atomically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly "at the same time" is not possible.  If you simply mean maintained to the same value whenever they may be accessed then:

```
class hardwareLayout
{
public: 
    void setAC( uint8_t r )
    {
        __disable_interrupts() ;
        regA = r ;
        regC = r ;
        __enable_interrupts() ;
    }

    void setB( uint8_t r ) { regB = r ; }

    uint8_t getA( uint8_t r ) const { return regA ; }
    uint8_t getB( uint8_t r ) const { return regB ; }
    uint8_t getC( uint8_t r ) const { return regC ; }

private:
    volatile uint8_t regA;
    volatile uint8_t regB;
    volatile uint8_t regC;
} ;
```

The enable/disable interrupt is necessary to ensure no other thread of execution to interrupt can preempt between setting A and setting C.  The actual means of doing that on your target will differ.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few answers,

In the strict case of your example, add a dummy member to the structure

```
struct hardwareLayout{
    uint8_t regA;
    uint8_t regB;
    uint8_t regC;
    uint8_t dummy;
}
```

Create a 32 bit value with the values you want in the correct bytes locations
And write the 32 bits to the register address.

```
void SetReg( uint8_t value)
{
    uint8_t tempArray[4];
    hardwareLayout *pHw = YOUR_HW_ADDR;
    uint32_t *pHwu32 = (uint32_t *)YOUR_HW_ADDR;
    uint32_t *pTempU32;

    tempArray[0] = value;
    tempArray[1] = pHw->regB;
    tempArray[2] = value;
    tempArray[3] = 0;

    pTempU32 = (uint32_t *)(&(tempArray[0]));
    *pHwu32 = *pTempU32;
}
```

If your two registers are not close enough in memory to write a single native integer size for your processor, then here's plan B.

What if instead of the two registers having the exact value, you kept them very close by writing the new value in stages. Starting at the old value, add or subtract one from each register, alternating, until they both equal the new value.

If neither of those work, then your hardware needs something that software can't do. The solution to that is to change the hardware. Use an FPGA write the two registers at once. Or some other HW solution based on your specific situation.